# AngularJS, подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? Не выводит Hello,world

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="helloWorldApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>#1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Создаем модель
        var model = "Hello, world"
        //Создаем модуль
        var helloWorldApp = angular.module ("helloWorldApp", []);
        //Добавляем контроллер
        helloWorldApp.controller = ("HelloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) { //Метод создающий контроллер
            $scope.message = model; //Передаем данные для представления
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">
<h1>{{message}}</h1> <!--Выводим Hello, world  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) - это функция.

Измените на

```
helloWorldApp.controller("HelloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) {
```

Кроме того стоит использовать последние версии фреймворка. Версия 1.0.6 - сильно устарела, и имеет множество отличий от последних версий.

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо Вам !